# Correr aplicación Android a más de un dispositivo a la vez

Tags: android, android-studio

Me pregunto si es posible compilar y debugar a la misma vez en varios dispositivos conectados con Android Studio.

**Conclusiones**
Para poder probar la app en multiples dispositivos, en la pantalla donde te deja escoger el dispositivo se puede selecionar mas de uno, con la tecla `ctrl` , hay ciertos paneles y opciones que no se pueden usar:
- El panel informativo de Memory/CPU/Network no se muestra

Si se usa Android Studio 2.0 Preview, el `Instant run` también queda deshabilitado.

Comment: cual es el objetivo de esto, es acaso realizar pruebas en distintos dispositivos al mismo tiempo? o únicamente subir rápidamente los ,apk a los dispositivos?

Comment: @Elenasys es simplemente para subir el .apk en todos los dispositivos, para testear todo a la vez, es decir smartphones y tabletas, y no tener que selecionar uno y despues otro.

Comment: Ok como te comentaba en mi respuesta puedes subir el .apk a varios dispositivos pero como es secuencial, es casí lo mismo que subir individualmente. En cuanto al debug, Android Studio únicamente puede debuguear un proceso por dispositivo =( ...

Comment: Seguiré investigando, me parece que la preview 2.0 de Android Studio, hay mejoras en este aspecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres a cargar al mismo tiempo el .apk en distintos dispositivos el `ADB` tenia esa limitante de solo cargar la aplicación en un dispositivo a la vez hace algunas versiones de SDK. Actualmente se puede realizar con :

```
adb devices
```

Como realiza la carga del archivo secuencialmente en los dispositivos yo sinceramente opto por ver si se carga en un dispositivo cargarlo inmediatamente al siguiente mediante "Run" (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> en Android Studio), tarda casí el mismo tiempo.

Si te refieres a debuggear únicamente se puede solo un único dispositivo a la vez. Puedes realizar lo que te muestro en la imagen pero al final solo un procesos puede ser debuggueado...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]